# How to draw this picture with Latex?

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, diagrams

Could some one help me to draw the following picture with Latex ( using only 1 picture) ?
Thank you SO MUCH for your help.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Dear Erik, I am pretty new with Latex and to bo honest I don't know where to start beside searching on Google but I cannot not find an answer on it.

Comment: What you need is called TikZ. Your simple drawing is covered in the tutorial of the manual: http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf

Comment: Although the tikz manual makes 800 pages, you should get to the point easily by looking at chapter 19. Trees are commons in tikz, see for instance http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how to get started.  I think it should make it clear enough how to continue to get the diagram you want.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my midway label/.style={midway,yshift=1.5in}]

  %% case 1
  \node[anchor=east] (A/left)         at (0,0)                  {$x$};
  \node[anchor=west] (A/right)        at ($(A/left)+(1in,0)$)   {$x$};
  \node[anchor=west] (A/right/up/1)   at ($(A/right)+(0,1in)$)  {$x+dx$};
  \node[anchor=west] (A/right/down/1) at ($(A/right)+(0,-1in)$) {$x-dx$};

  \path (A/left) -- (A/right) node [my midway label] {Case 1};

  \draw[blue] (A/left) -- (A/right);
  \draw[red]  (A/left) -- (A/right/up/1.west);
  \draw[red]  (A/left) -- (A/right/down/1.west);

  %% case 2
  \node[anchor=east] (B/left)         at ($(A/right)+(1in,0)$) {$x$};
  \node[anchor=west] (B/right)        at ($(B/left)+(1in,0)$)  {$x$};

  \path (B/left) -- (B/right) node [my midway label] {Case 2};

  \draw[blue] (B/left) -- (B/right);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are other ways of doing this as suggested by @clement .  But this approach will help familiarize yourself with some basics of TikZ.

I'll explain a few of the details here:

## node syntax

```
\node[<optional arguments>] (<optional node name>) at (<position>) {<content>};
```

The one part of this syntax that you *cannot* omit is the content.

I use the power of the `calc` library to help place nodes relative to each other.  That's what's happening when I write:

```
at ($(<previously defined node name>)+(<vector>)$)
```

When I opened the `tikzpicture` environment, I defined my own private *style*.  This is a way of helping manage the picture.  The idea is that I'm going to define a node between two points along a path and then shift it in the $y$ direction.

In this case, I used a particular instance of path syntax:

```
\path (<1st node name>) -- (<2nd node name>) node[<optional argument] {<content>};
```

Note that in this case `node` is not a control sequence but just a bare word.

Comment: +1 for the long vary gracious tikz introduction for a newbie.